# Sending multiple commands with psexec

Tags: powershell

I'd like to condense

```
psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im soffice*
psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im swriter*
psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im scalc*
psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im simpress*
```

Into one psexec command. Normally I'd try the `&` operator to do `so & so` but since I'm doing this all in PS, it doesn't seem to like that. I tried an array of `()` and `""` but it doesn't seem to like those either.

### EDIT [answer]

Ended up just copying a `.cmd` (BAT) file and making a shortcut in my `$PROFILE` locally.

```
function flushlibra
{
param([string]$user = "")
if ($user -eq "")
{
    $user = Read-Host "User to nuke LibraOffice proccesses: "
}

psexec -c "\\unc\path\to\flushlibra.cmd" $user
}
```

`.cmd` file

```
taskkill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq %1" /im soffice*
taskkill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq %1" /im swriter*
taskkill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq %1" /im scalc*
taskkill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq %1" /im simpress*
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

psexec allows you to invoke a batch script remotely, too, not just single commands.  Use the `-c` switch to indicate that the script should be copied to the remote system.

So if you locally have a script KillProcs.cmd:

```
taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im soffice*
taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im swriter*
taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im scalc*
taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im simpress*
```

Then you can run that remotely like this

```
psexec \\server -c c:\localpath\KillProcs.cmd
```

Comment: I over thought this. This ended up being the best. I ended up just passing a parameter to a .cmd script

Answer (score 3):

I always use like this way :) and works properly

```
psexec \\COMPUTER -e cmd /c (COMMAND1 ^& COMMAND2 ^& COMMAND3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to concatencate commands on a single line then use the statement separator `;` e.g.:

```
psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im soffice*; psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im swriter* ; psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im scalc* ; psexec \\server taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $username" /im simpress*
```

From looking at the PSEXEC usage, it doesn't appear to allow you to specify multiple programs in a single invocation of PSEXEC.

BTW you could use PowerShell's remoting capability - assuming `server` has WMF 2.0 or higher installed and has enabled WSMan remoting e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server {Stop-Process -Name soffice*,swriter*,scalc*,simpress* -Force}
```

If you can't go the remoting route, another approach would be to create a PowerShell function:

```
function Stop-RemoteProcess([string]$ComputerName, [string[]]$Programs, [string]$UserName)
{
    foreach ($program in $Programs)
    {
        psexec "\\$ComputerName" taskill /f /t /fi "USERNAME eq $UserName" /im $program
    }
}

Stop-RemoteProcess server soffice*,swriter*,scalc*,simpress* JohnDoe
```