# PsExec fails to connect on second call

Tags: powershell, remote-access, psexec

I'm running into an issue with connecting to remote machine A from machine B using psexec.

```
PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

The handle is invalid.
Connecting to <server>...
Couldn't access <server>:
```

The confusing part for me is that right before this, we have a script call to machine A from machine B that works just fine. (this is being done from a powershell script if that's of relevance).

This is the first call (that works)

```
& psexec \\$computer_name -u "<domain>/<user>" -p "<pass>" -w "<folder>" "<program1>" 2
```

This is the second call (executed directly after the first)

```
& psexec \\$computer_name -u "<domain>/<user>" -p "<pass>" -w "<folder>" "<program1>" 1
```

When I take just that part of the script and run it from another machine (machine C pointing to machine A), I can get it to work, which makes me think it's unlikely that the two are interfering with each other. I've looked for a way to disconnect psexec from a computer, but I didn't find anything, so I'm not sure if there's a way.

I found an answer on superuser suggesting that it could be limited by sessions https://superuser.com/questions/200938/psexec-the-handle-is-invalid, but I checked and found that there is only one connection active.

Any help figuring out what is wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this and, playing around with it, I've found a workaround that's resolved this for me.

If they're the same as in the first call, try removing the account credentials from the second call. Your calls would then look like:

First:
    & psexec \\$computer_name -u "domain/user" -p "pass" -w "folder" "program1" 2

Second:
    & psexec \\$computer_name -w "folder" "program1" 1

Comment: If you verify that this workaround works, please add some specifics to your answer and clean it up to make it more "answery".

Comment: Edited. New here, so forgive me.

Comment: Thank you!  This solved it for us. We were able to execute both commands.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. My solution was to place all the remote commands in a batch file `PSEXEC_COMMANDS.cmd` and run `PsExec` just once:

```
PsExec \\<computer> <options> -c PSEXEC_COMMANDS.cmd <arguments>
```

---

- Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393887/9718438
- More info on the `-c` switch from *PsExec*'s author [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/psexec):

  > [I]f it's an executable on the local system that you want to execute on the remote system, specify the -c switch and the file's local path. The -c switch directs PsExec to copy the specified executable to the remote system for execution and delete the executable from the remote system when the program has finished running.